# ASP. NET checkbox onchange

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a page displaying a table of data pulled from a database. The data is filtered to show the last 6 months of data. I want to put a check box on the page where the user can click on the checkbox to toggle between seeing all the data from all-time to the filtered last 6 months of data. Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="datefilter" class="form-check-input" onChange="this.form.submit()">
Display All Time Data
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string[] datefilter, string SearchString, string sortOrder, int? page)
    {
        DateTime testDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
        var PatientID = from p in db.PatientTbls
                        select p;
        if (datefilter == null)
        {
            PatientID = PatientID.Where(s => s.CreationDate >= testDate);
        }
        PatientID = PatientID.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreationDate);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
        {
            PatientID = PatientID.Where(s => s.ReadOnModel.Contains(SearchString) || s.ToBeMarkedOnLaser.Contains(SearchString) || s.Brand.Contains(SearchString));
        }
        return View(PatientID.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 150));
    }
```

My thought was to have the checkbox re-submit the form with the new checked value and the "if" statement would then filter or not filter the results.  The issue is when I check the box, it refreshes the page which then clears the checkbox.  Also once I check the box once, it forever does not run the date filter query.  Any help would be great.

PS. I'm new to all this so please bear with me.

Comment: Why don't you go with jquery and make an ajax call?

Comment: Why not pull the entire result to client side and apply filters at front end according to the users selection? This will reduce the round trips to server.

Answer (score 0):

Well try OnMouseUp / Down... -  OnChange might be to late ...

---

You could use AJAX to call an action - simply said as example like:

```
 function loadDoc() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  xhttp.open("GET", "/controller/filteredindex ...", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

A) You might prepare the path with RAZOR ... where filteredIndex
is just returning the proper data to be displayed.

B) You could also inquire the checkbox status within the action ... in order to create an updated PROPER view. If you cover the checkbox within your (view)model, it simple to set or reset it. So the returning
view shows everything like you want.

AJAX from: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp
Best regards, Oliver